# sp_executesql not showing desired result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sp-executesql

I am working on SQL in SQL Server and come across this problem where,

```
set @sqlString=N'select @max=MAX('+@columnName+') from @temp';
exec sp_executesql @sqlString,
             N'@temp as Table_Type readonly, @max nvarchar(max)', @temp ,@max;
```

I have tested this sql statement without parameters and it was working but like this it's showing null in @max.
Please help me out where am i going wrong!!

Comment: Whats the @columnName?

Comment: it's a variable containing column name of the table.. and @temp is a temporary variable of same table type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to point that the `max` parameter is `output`. Try this:

```
set @sqlString=N'select @max=MAX('+@columnName+') from @temp';
exec sp_executesql @sqlString,
             N'@temp as Table_Type readonly, @max nvarchar(max) output', @temp ,@max output;
```

You can check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262499) example as well.